# How do I transfer my gta 5 saves from one account to the other on the same pc?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I recently made my own steam account. I can still play the games from the other account, my dad's, but when i play gta online it says to login to social club. It has never asked me before. I asked my dad and he said to transfer the saves from his account to mine but I don't know how. I don't know where they are or where to put them. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Like Campaign or Online?

Comment: i want online because i didnt get very far in story mode

Answer (score 1):

Progress made in GTA Online is saved on Rockstar's servers. You cannot copy or amend this data. To access your account simply log in to Rockstar SocialClub using your login credentials and start GTA Online.
Alternatively, if you would like to use your dad's account to play GTA Online you'll need to ask him to sign-in for you.